# I don't understand the difference between Django-Rest-Framework's built-in Hyperlink's and vs. HAL

Tags: django, rest, asp.net-web-api, django-rest-framework

I've never really heard of [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) until I started working on a new project that is making use of it.  From what I can tell, it's basically a way to easily follow links to traverse your way around a restful API's structure.

So if I understand this correctly, both tools are to make it easier to traverse around an API's documentation to see all the different means of communicating with said API.   Essentially both of these are tools used for documentation purposes only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REST APIs must be hypertext driven. It's not merely for documentation purposes, but for driving all interaction with the API. If you're not driving the interaction through links and clients are building URIs from templates in documentation, it's not RESTful. The authors of Django-REST-Framework themselves recognize the name is inadequate.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/rest-hypermedia-hateoas/

You should read the links provided in that document, specially this one:

http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven

With that in mind, your REST API has to use a data format where links are standardized so clients know how to parse them. This would constrain most APIs to use HTML or XML, but since JSON is such a popular data-exchange format, there are some efforts into designing conventions for adding hypermedia-awareness to any format, like HAL.

Django-REST-Framework supports hyperlinks in the HTML output, but -- AFAIK -- it has no support for hyperlinks in other formats. You can use HAL-JSON if you want, but you'll have to implement support for it.

Comment: Indeed that is a great explanation. 


@Pedro Werneck: May I ask how do you call it if clients are building URIs from templates in documentation? Is Web API a good name for it?

Comment: @nik_m Web implies hyperlinking. Most of the time I call them HTTP APIs. If I want to be passive-aggressive, I call them street-REST APIs (the REST you learn on the streets), or paraphrasing Roy Fielding in the linked blog post, X-rated APIs (too much coupling).